# Is it possible to start jenkins through proxychains

Tags: github, proxy, jenkins

I have code repository on GitHub and CI server (Ubuntu) with Jenkins behind firewall.

So I set proxy settings to jenkins and it works fine (e.g. i can see the availvable plugins).
And I configured proxy settings in .gitconfig.
Also i have id_rsa in jenkins home/.ssh directory.

But jenkins can't perform git clone during job execution because of an error:

ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out

Jenkins user successfully performs proxychains git clone operation in terminal.

Is it possible to force jenkins works through proxychains? Or could anybody advice me some alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem wih this:
http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2008/04/08/getting-ssh-to-connect-through-a-socks-proxy/

Answer (score 0):

I have solved similar problem using STDIO proxy tunnel.

- update `~/.ssh/config`:

  ```
  Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    ProxyCommand gitproxy %h %p
  ```
- create `~/bin/gitproxy` script with this content:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  exec socat STDIO PROXY:proxy.com:$1:$2,proxyport=8080,proxyauth=user:password
  ```